# Tools to put pixel ruler guides to the image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, ruler

I'm using Photoshop/Illustrator to design the layout of my game's title screen. When I have finished, in addition to exporting each button/image for the programmer to implement, I also want to let the programmer know the exact coordinates of where to put each button.

As far as I have searched I cannot find an easy way to do this. Currently I use the ruler tool to measure and type in the measured number by myself. I am looking for a tool that after you dragged the ruler to measure, the guide is automatically put in the image.

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Ah, I wanted to put a x-y coordinate guides of desired point directly on to the image. The manual way of measure and put a text in it, is not feasible for large volume of images.

Comment: I think that could be fixed with a edit.